# How to implement radio button check in JSP JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I have created a web application (i.e. an Ecommerce site). Here I have implemented a radio button where I am selecting one from two options. When I select any of them, then other elements should be visible. For example: I have a time slot option. When I click on multi option (from radio button check) then there are 5 or 6 more options should be displayed. And when I select uni option (from radio button check) then there are 1 option should be visible. I have done with that part. I got stuck where I need to send all those parameters to my servlet controller.
I want when multi option selected then only those 5 or 6 parameters should be sent when forms submitted. Below code is to show and hide div for selected radio button. I am facing problem when I select uni option, then I am getting as message - some parameters missing.

```
function selectoption(id){
    if(id == 'multitime'){
        document.getElementById('multidiv').style.display= 'contents';
        document.getElementById('unidiv').style.display = 'none';
     }else{
        document.getElementById('unidiv').style.display = 'contents';
        document.getElementById('multidiv').style.display = 'none';
     }      
 }
Below code is to submit all data of form and send to controller of springboot.

    function setpincode(){
        var pincode = document.getElementById('pincode').value;
        var delivercityid = document.getElementById('deliverycityid').value;
        var status = "";
        if(document.getElementById('activestatus').checked){
            status = document.getElementById('activestatus').value;
        }else{
            status = document.getElementById('inactivestatus').value;
        }
        var timeslot = "";
        if(document.getElementById('multitime').checked){
            timeslot =  document.getElementById('multitime').value;
        }else{
            timeslot =  document.getElementById('unitime').value;
        }
        var nightservice = "";
        if(document.getElementById('multinightservice').checked){
            nightservice = document.getElementById('multinightservice').value;
        }else{
            nightservice = document.getElementById('uninightservice').value;
        }
        
        var midnightcharge = document.getElementById('midnightcharge').value;
        
        var morningservice = "";
        if(document.getElementById('activeservice').checked){
            morningservice = document.getElementById('activeservice').value;    
        }else{
            morningservice = document.getElementById('inactiveservice').value;
        }
        var earlymorningcharge=document.getElementById('morningcharge').value;
        var fixedtimeservice = "";
        if(document.getElementById('afixedtimeservice').checked){
          fixedtimeservice=document.getElementById('afixedtimeservice').value;
        }else{
       fixedtimeservice=document.getElementById('inacfixedtimeservice').value;
        }
        var fixedcharge = document.getElementById('fixedcharge').value;
        var fixedtimeslot = document.getElementById('fixedtimeslot').value;
        var deliverycharge = document.getElementById('deliverycharge').value;
        var deliveryslot = document.getElementById('deliveryslot').value;
        var unitimeslot = document.getElementById('unitimeslot').value;
        var deliverytime = document.getElementById('deliverytime').value;
        document.getElementById('addpincodeform').submit();
    }
Below is my HTML code: 
<form action="addpincode" method="post" id="addpincodeform" 
      name="addpincodeform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="floating-form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mt-4">
              <div class="floating-label">
                <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="pincode" 
                   id="pincode" placeholder=" "> 
                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                    <label>Pin Code</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mt-4">
             <div class="floating-label">
                <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="city" 
                      id="city" placeholder=" "> 
                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                    <label>City</label>
              </div>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <h6>Status</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
             <input type="radio" name="status" id="activestatus" value="1">Active 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <input type="radio" name="status" id="inactivestatus" value="0"> 
                                     InActive
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-2">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
              <h6>Time Slot</h6>
            </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <input type="radio" name="timeslot" id="multitime" value="multi" 
                onchange="selectoption('multitime')">Multi 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <input type="radio" name="timeslot" id="unitime" value="uni" 
                    onchange="selectoption('unitime')">Uni
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div style="display:none;" id="multidiv">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-2">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
             <h6>Mid Night Service</h6>
            </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <input type="radio" name="nightservice" id="multinightservice" 
                        value="yes">Yes 
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <input type="radio" name="nightservice" id="uninightservice" 
                value="no">No
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-2">
         <div class="floating-label">
          <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="midnightcharge" 
                  id="midnightcharge" placeholder=" "> 
           <span class="highlight"></span>
             <label>Mid Night Charge</label>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
              <h6>Early Morning Service</h6>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
           <input type="radio" name="morningservice" id="activeservice" 
                  value="yes">Yes 
          </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <input type="radio" name="morningservice" id="inactiveservice" 
               value="no"> No
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-2">
      <div class="floating-label">
        <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="earlymorningcharge" 
            id="morningcharge" placeholder=" "> 
          <span class="highlight"></span>
          <label>Early Morning Charge</label>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-2">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
             <h6>Fixed Time Service</h6>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
        <input type="radio" name="fixedtimeservice" id="afixedtimeservice" 
                 value="yes">Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
         <input type="radio" name="fixedtimeservice" id="inacfixedtimeservice" 
               value="no"> No
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-2">
            <div class="floating-label">
              <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="fixedcharge" 
                  id="fixedcharge" placeholder=" "> 
               <span class="highlight"></span>
            <label>Fixed Charge</label>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
          <div class="floating-label">
            <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="deliverycharge" 
                           id="deliverycharge" placeholder=" "> 
            <span class="highlight"></span>
            <label>Standard Delivery Charge</label>
          </div>
         </div>                                                     
        <div style="display:none;" id="unidiv">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="floating-label">
             <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="unitimeslot" 
                  id="unitimeslot" placeholder=" "> 
              <span class="highlight"></span>
                <label>Uni Time Slot</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="floating-label">
         <input class="floating-input" type="text" name="deliverytime" 
                      id="deliverytime" placeholder=" "> 
            <span class="highlight"></span>
             <label>Last Delivery Time</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger px-5" 
          onclick="setpincode()">Save</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: show html code as well

Comment: I have updated my query.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this ?

Comment: Yes, I have solved this.